# Google app engine subfolder not working - PHP

Tags: php, python, google-app-engine, yaml

my app.yaml is like below

```
handlers:

- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /static
  script: /static/index.html

- url: /
  script: index.html
```

So what i need is when  i access the url http://xyz.appspot.com/static ...it should show the content of `static/index.html`....But i get not found error...whereas http://xyz.appspot.com/static/index.html is working fine

Comment: Maybe you don't need the /static in front of the index.html?

Comment: i removed /static but still its not working..

Comment: Is the other index.html working?

Comment: Did you try /static/index.html without the first slash? static/index.html

Comment: yea main index.html is working...yea i removed 1st slash too...still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not defined a handler, you need something like

```
handlers:

- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /static/
  static_files: static/index.html
  upload: static/index.html

- url: /
  static_files: index.html
  upload: index.html
```